# C# Getting info from a web id

Tags: c#

I want to get text from a website, but from a certain element, does any one have any clues?

From example the code I have to make text form a text box to a website textbox is

```
webBrowser1.Document
           .GetElementById("MySchool_login")
           .SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are trying to do here, you initially talk about "screen scraping" a website and then provide a code sample which sets an attribute.

Comment: also you want to do it in c# or javascript? server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called as [screen scrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping). You can use [Watin](http://watin.org/) for this. Or else you can use [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) and [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to achieve this also.